# Busca de dados com Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Tenho um projeto em Asp.Net MVC onde preciso trabalhar com um grande volume de dados. Para obtê-los do Banco de Dados (Microsoft SQL Server) usando Entity Framework 4 conheço basicamente três formas:

**1ª forma:**

```
var resultado = from p in db.Pessoa
                where p.DataNasc > x
                select new { Id = p.PessoaId, Nome = p.Nome };
```

**2ª forma:**

```
var cmd = string.format(@"SELECT p.PessoaId, p.Nome
                          FROM Pessoa p
                          WHERE p.DataNasc > {0}", x);

var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
var resultado = objectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<PessoaCustom>(cmd).ToList<PessoaCustom>();
```

**3ª forma:**

```
var resultado = db.Pessoa.Where(p => p.DataNasc > x).Select(p => new {Id = p.PessoaId, Nome = p.Nome});
```

> Gostaria de, juntamente com o nome de cada forma, uma resposta que
>   abordasse qual a forma mais apropriada para obter um grande volume de
>   dados levando em consideração o **uso de memória RAM**, **processamento** e a
>   **query enviada ao banco** *(pois as vezes o Entity constrói querys muito
>   complexas para instruções simples que acabam por consumir mais
>   processamento do servidor de banco de dados)*.

Comment: O que é, para você, um grande volume de dados?

Comment: Mais de 5000 registros pra mim já é muita coisa, rsrsrs... :)

Comment: Você fará o que com essa listagem de dados? é uma tela de listagem? é uma rotina de processamento? Qual a necessidade? Para cada problema existe uma solução mais específica. Não faz muito sentido em simplesmente listar por listar, se não for para um relatório.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jedais, não vejo sentido em tentar comparar Raw SQL (forma 2) e Linq (Query - forma 1, Method - forma 2).

Eu usaria uma Raw SQL apenas em situações em que ganhar uns poucos "ms" resulte em um grande ganho, ou seja, naquelas poucas consultas ("~5%") que respondem por "~95%" do programa.

A forma 1 basicamente trabalha como uma `syntactic sugar` da forma 3, esta vai apresentar apenas um pequeno overhead no momento da compilação, no mais ambas são identicas.

A forma 2, aconselho que utilize:

```
var query = @"SELECT PessoaId, Nome FROM Pessoa WHERE DataNasc > @p0"
var resultado = from p in db.Pessoa.SqlQuery<PessoaModel>(query, x).ToList();
```

O problema desta forma, é que não é possivel trabalhar com tipos dinamicos, então você vai precisar retornar a propria Entity (default), ou algum tipo complexo ou primitivo... uma solução de contorno seria utilizar um tipo dynamic como o ExpandoObject.

Por fim, temos uma solução que é o meio termo, Entity SQL... neste caso te aconselho a ler o seguinte material, uma vez que Entoty SQL é uma linguagem completamente a parte, e a mesma difere em alguns pontos importantes do TSQL e PLSQL.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb399560(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 3):

O Entity Framework é um Framework "robusto" que trata vários fatores para você, como o Lazy Loading, Detecção de Mudanças, Proxies, dentre outras. Se você desabilitar esses recursos você terá um grande ganho de desempenho.

Por exemplo, sua consulta desabilitando seria assim:

```
var db = new dbContext();
db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;//verifica mudanças no objeto
db.Configuration.EnsureTransactionsForFunctionsAndCommands = false;//define o valor que determina se as funções e comandos SQL deve sempre ser executada em uma transação. EF6
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;//Desabilita o LazyLoading
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;//Desabilita o proxy
db.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = false;
db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

var resultado = db.Pessoa.AsNoTracking().Where(p => p.DataNasc > x).Select(p => new {Id = p.PessoaId, Nome = p.Nome});
```

Outro fator que influencia é a versão que está usando. o EF hoje já se encontra na versão 6, você está usando a 4. Ele foi melhorado em muitos aspectos, performance foi um deles.

Outra opção seria usar outros Frameworks apenas para pesquisas, como o [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net). Isso te daria um grande ganho de desempenho, ainda mais com a versão desatualizada do EF.

E por fim, se quer a forma mais rápida (e mais trabalhosa) você pode optar por ADO puro.

Deixarei alguns links de referências para melhor entendimento.

- [Melhorando Desempenho com EF](http://blog.albertomonteiro.net.br/2015/07/20/entity-framework-melhorando-performance-para-consulta-readonly/)
- [10 Dicas para melhor o desempenho com o EF](http://www.macoratti.net/13/10/ef5_mdes1.htm)
- [EF Performance Otimization](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2015/entity-framework-performance-optimization/)
- [Good Pratices with EF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/547278/4843158)